# How to validate links before moving to different location

Tags: 7, forms, blocks, navigation

This would be most simple functional question in Drupal 7.
Now below mentioned things are mandatory to do and cant change the functionality.
1) I have created a custom block in module.
2) I have included form like below:-

```
function usercontent_block_view($delta='') 
{

   $block = array();    
   switch($delta)
   {
     case 'user_front_page' :        
       $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('genre_all_login');                       
     break;
   }
   return $block; 
}
```

3) Now I have some other content in block but which put me in trouble is shown below:-

```
function genre_all_login($form) {
  $form['new_user'] = array(
  '#type' => 'item',
  '#markup' => l('Add New User','http://www.google.com'),            
    );
    return $form; 
  }
```

4) So it includes a link which will move me to Google once clicked.
5) Now I want to validate certain content inside the block before user navigates to Google.So if the condition doesn't match then I will stop the user by showing an error message and hence user cannot traverse to Google.

Please tell me if it is possible or should I use different technique to handle this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a client side validation. Like below,

1. Add an ID attribute to the external link

   ```
   $form['new_user'] = array(
     '#type' => 'item',
     '#markup' => l('Add New User','http://www.google.com', array('attributes' => array('id' => 'external-link'))),            
   );
   ```
2. Add a JavaScript code to validate and preventi the click.

   ```
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery('#external-link').click(function(event) {
       // Perform your validation. If the validation fails prevent events default behavior.
       validated = false;
       if (!validated) {
         event.preventDefault(); // You can also use return false instead of prevent default.
       }
     });
   });
   ```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks. In my scenario I want to do PHP validation. Does Drupal provides anything out of box for PHP validation for links?

Comment: I will try to achieve functionality using this. Thanks for response